# What could be the possible reason for Target insert row count in log file to differ from actual inserts in database?

Tags: mysql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

The issue I am facing is that even though the records read from source and records inserted into the target match, the same is not being reflected in the Source/Target statics section of Workflow Monitor.

Workflow Monitor : 28387 Rejected rows : 1
MYSQL count : 23527

There was scenario that rows were getting silently rejected due to datatype conversion error varchar to int. There is only one row in source which should get rejected but it is silently rejecting more than 5k records.

Need to find the root cause.

Comment: match source to target then figure out why silent rejects.Other than that I don't see how we can help.

Comment: There can be many possibilities - like data type mismatch, unique key violation, data length mismatch, trying to insert date into a non date field. I should say debug to find out - 1. set session to verbose mode and pass only missing records and see where its dropping off. 2. You can use informatica debug too to find out where its dropping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug issue by  using  an aggregator , group by on all columns and get count of records and load that count into a flat file. This gives number of records mapping is processing.Iterate this step by uncheking group by on each column until your difference in count of records is equal to count of records in aggregator.

This helps to identify which column is causing the issue.